# Django - MigrationSchemaMissing error windows

Tags: django, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect Oracle 11g with django through cx_Oracle
here i am able to fetch data from my database and show it in command prompt.
in settings.py i have wrote-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'XE',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '1521'
    }
}
```

and in view.py for extracting data i have written-

```
import cx_Oracle

# create connection

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('name/pass@//localhost:1521/xe')
print(conn.version)
# create cursor
# cur.execute(sql_create)
#print('table created')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from des')
res = cur.fetchall()
list = []
for r in res:
    list.append(r)
    print(r)
print(list)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

here i have used the list data for showing dynamically in the frontend.
in model.py i have written-

```
from django.db import models
class Destination(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField
```

But while migration i am facing the below errors-

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 68, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 331, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 523, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\static prac\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\static prac\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models

class Destination(models.Model):
    # id = models.IntegerField()
    # There will be a default id filed automatically, so no need for this

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Next

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: C:\Users\User\Desktop\static prac>python manage.py migrate
11.2.0.2.0
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
travello.Destination: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.

Comment: class Destination(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()                                                                                       after changing this the next error-                                                                                         return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword